# I want to use .load() with query value, jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to load the feed value with a user id, but does not.  The full url is

```
http://localhost/feed/feeds.php/?userid=xxyy

var f = <? echo $_POST['xy']; ?>
    $('#feed').bind('click',function(){
        $('#feed1').load("http://localhost/feed/feeds.php/",{'userid':[f]);
    });
```

Can I use the url directly>

Either way I the page does not load on clicking `<div id="feed"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

there's a `}` missing:

```
.load("http://localhost/feed/feeds.php/",{ 'userid': [f] });
```

**EDIT #1**
and i don't think you need the `[]`...

Comment: I want the .load, but for some reason it does not work

I used iframe, still does not solve the issue though